# PHP How to find if 2 dates are equal

Tags: php

I have a date field that submits the chosen dates and I want to find out if the end date is today.

So for example I want to compare 21-May-2012(today) to 21-May-2012(submitted) and see if they match or not.

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if ( strtotime($current) != strtotime($sumbit) )
```

Or just simplier:

```
$currentDate  = '21-May-2012';
$submit = '21-May-2012';

if ($submit != $currentDate)
  echo 'Different';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentDate  = '21-May-2012';
$submitDate = '21-May-2012';

if ($submitDate == $currentDate)
  echo 'Same';
else
  echo 'Different';
```